# Viewpager2 Android : A Next button on the view generates two slides to the right

Tags: android, kotlin, sliding

I'm stuck on viewpager2 problem on Android.
I have a viewpager2 creating some fragments depending on the position. Each fragment has a next button to navigate horizontally in the view pager.

But when I asked for the next page from the button, *I had the action of sliding twice.* It like the method createFragment from the adapter was called twice, due to the preload of the fragment borders...

**Activity who manage the view pager:**

```
class ConfigurationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var viewPager : ViewPager2? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_configuration)

        viewPager = viewPager2
        val instance = this

        viewPager!!.apply {
            isUserInputEnabled = true
            orientation = ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL

            if(viewPager!!.adapter == null)
                viewPager!!.adapter = ConfigAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle, instance, 2)
        }

        viewPager!!.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                super.onPageSelected(position)          
                currentItem = position
            }
        })
    }

    companion object{
        private var currentItem : Int = 0

        fun nextPage(instance : ConfigurationActivity, currentPosition : Int?){
            instance.viewPager!!.currentItem = currentItem + 1
        }
    }
}
```

**The FragmentStateAdapter**

```
class ConfigAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, lc : Lifecycle, private val instance : ConfigurationActivity, configSnapshot : ArrayList<Configuration>) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lc) {
    private val configSize = configSnapshot.size

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        val length = configSize + 3
        instance.pageIndicatorView.count = length
        return length
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        Timber.d("creating fragment at position $position")
        return when(position){
                0 -> WelcomeFragment(instance)
                in 1..configSize /* position between 1 and configSize (included) */ -> ConfigureFragment(instance, position-1)
                1 + configSize -> IdentifyFragment(instance)
                2 + configSize -> EndFragment()
                else -> Fragment()
            }
    }
}
```

**A fragment example:**

```
class ConfigureFragment(private val instance : ConfigurationActivity, private val configPosition: Int) : Fragment() {
...
   view.button_continue.setOnClickListener {
       nextPage(instance, configPosition+1)
   }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this way:-

- First of all change `viewPager` variable `private` to `public` in Activity like removing `private` keyword.

  `var viewPager : ViewPager2? = null`
- In fragment change `setOnClickListener` method like below:

  `view.button_continue.setOnClickListener {
     instance!!.viewPager!!.arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT)
  }`

*Suggestion:

- In fragment, we can get parent activity instance and use this way instead of passing activity instance to each fragment.

  `val instance = ((activity as AppCompatActivity) as ConfigurationActivity)`

Comment: Thanks for this response, I applied the suggested code, but it doesn't change the issue.

Comment: Instead of `ViewPager2` try to use `ViewPager` only. I have tried and it works.

Comment: @Kamenber Have you try like this new way in `setOnClickListener` as per changed(updated) code?

Comment: @Kamenber      Also you can comment this  `viewPager!!.registerOnPageChangeCallback...` code and try it.